# Address Sanitizer detecting and handling runtime erros but not showing

Tags: c, debugging, memory, buffer

I am getting some undefined behavior in my code causing segmentation fault. But when i built it with `-fsanitize=address` , they were handled well and not throwing any segmentation faults. Came to know that AddressSanitizer has changed their behavior (buffer overruns, leaks etc) and executing the program successfully.

```
gcc -g -o scrmenu -fsanitize=address -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 caomenu.c superbox.c -L/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/lib -L/usr/include/ -L/usr/lib64/ -lclntsh -lcurses
```

But i want to know the actual errors/undefined behaviors in my code. so to get those error reports i have set the option `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2` after reading it in some blog thread post. But it is indicating a fatal error but not providing exact error details. instead it's throwing below errors which is not leaving any clue.

```
 Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
    [Detaching after fork from child process 696460]
    [Detaching after fork from child process 696460]


==696450==LeakSanitizer has encountered a fatal error.
==696450==HINT: For debugging, try setting environment variable LSAN_OPTIONS=verbosity=1:log_threads=1
==696450==HINT: LeakSanitizer does not work under ptrace (strace, gdb, etc)
[Inferior 1 (process 696450) exited with code 01]
Missing separate debuginfos, use: yum debuginfo-install glibc-2.28-189.5.0.1.el8_6.x86_64 libasan-8.5.0-16.0.1.el8_7.x86_64 libgcc-8.5.0-16.0.1.el8_7.x86_64 libnsl-2.28-189.5.0.1.el8_6.x86_64 libstdc++-8.5.0-15.0.2.el8.x86_64 ncurses-libs-6.1-9.20180224.el8.x86_64 numactl-libs-2.0.12-13.el8.x86_64 sssd-client-2.7.3-4.0.1.el8_7.1.x86_64
```

definitely Addresssinitizer is detecting desired run time errors. Is there any way that i could see the details of them?

Comment: Did you set `LSAN_OPTIONS`?

Comment: yes @Gerhardh                                                                                                                        `export ASAN_OPTIONS=abort_on_error=1:report_objects=1:sleep_before_dying=60`

`export LSAN_OPTIONS=verbosity=1:log_threads=1`